# how to Acces a Button/Textbox..... from mainwindow in class

Tags: c#, wpf, oop

Im new at OOP and im wondering how i can say in my edit Class, get this textbox from the mainwindow and clear it. I tried this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Edit edit = new Edit();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
        }

        private void ClearBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //TxtBox.Clear();
            edit.Clear();
            
        }
    }
```

Edit class

```
public class Edit
    {
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();

        public void Clear()
        {
            main.TxtBox.Clear();
          
        }
        public Edit()
        {
            
        }

    }
```

Comment: Pass `MainWindow` as a parameter instead of creating a new instance in the `Edit` class.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me why you would need to clear the `MainWindow`'s text box from another class, as it's not practical in a real-world situation, but here you go:

```
public class Edit
{
    public void Clear(MainWindow window)
    {
        window.TxtBox.Clear();
    }
}
```

Another way to do it would be to pass the `MainWindow` into the `Edit` class's constructor, because I can see that you are instantiating `Edit` from the `MainWindow` class anyways.

```
public class Edit
{
    private MainWindow _window;

    public Edit(MainWindow window)
    {
        _window = window;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _window.TxtBox.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but what parameter should give in the Edit edit = new Edit(); ?                 It was asked in one of my school exams yeah i know :)

Comment: `Edit edit = new Edit(this)`

Comment: @Ogun if you use my first suggestion, then it's `Edit edit = new Edit()`. If you use the second suggestion, then it's `Edit edit = new Edit(this)`.  Either way should work.

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to access controls of MainWindow from different classes you could use a similiar code:

```
MainWindow MWin = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
MWin.TxtBox.Clear();
```